# ACL implementation using setuid

Tags: acl, setuid

I am working on an assignment that mainly deals with the following topic:

[image]

The main idea is to run a program as fakeroot that elevates the privileges of one user to read the file of the owner. If user1 is the owner then fakeroot allows user2 to read user1's file by changing its setuid.

I am not able to grasp how it is possible to implement ACLs using setuid. I was under the impression that ACL permission can only be changed using setfacl. I would like to know how one would go about solving this problem. I am fairly new to this domain and any insight would be helpful

Comment: `setuid` is not "fake" root. If the owner of the file is root and it has the `setuid` bit, it will run with root's effective uid. Once the program runs as root, it could do anything that root can do. to my understanding, you don't need to actually implement ACL, but to create a sort of alternative to it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by creating an alternative to an acl?